# What causes the semi-annual mesospheric meteoric potassium variability?

Tags: atmosphere, upper-atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, atmospheric-chemistry

In a recent study presented in the article [First global observations of the mesospheric potassium layer](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2014GL060801/full) (Dawkins et al. 2014), space-borne resonance fluorescence observations confirmed previous LIDAR observations of a semi-annual variability of mesospheric meteoric $\ce{K}$, which is very different from the annual (seasonal) pattern observed for other metals such as $\ce{Na}$ and $\ce{Fe}$.

**What causes the semi-annual mesospheric meteoric potassium variability?**

Answer (score 5):

Recent observations and modelling by Plane et al. (2015) and Plane et al. (2014) have described the most likely mechanisms for why potassium has its unique semi-annual variability, with a small summertime maximum and minima occurring at the equinoxes (Plane et al. 2015).  The semi-annual variability is consistent across the globe (Plane et al. 2014).

In both papers, the cause of the unique semi-annual variability are narrowed down to 2 main atmospheric chemical dynamics, based in no small part on unique K chemical properties:

(*Note: MLT = Mesosphere-Lower Thermosphere*)

- In summertime, the maxima observed is due to the cooler MLT temperatures being low enough to neutralise K<sup>+</sup> ions to K.
- During the equinoxes, O is at a minima, while CO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub> exhibit a maxima - so, according to Plane et al. (2015)'s model, decreasing O, while increasing CO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub> causes a reaction with K to form KHCO<sub>3</sub>, thus resulting in K being at a minima.

According to their models, KHCO<sub>3</sub> returns to K by largely temperature independent photolysis.

Plane et al. (2014) describe there is a slight decrease in K in high latitudes in the presence of polar mesospheric clouds.

**References**

Plane et al. 2015, [Resolving the strange behavior of extraterrestrial potassium in the upper atmosphere](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2014GL060334/full), *Geophysical Research Letters*

Plane et al. 2014, [The Mesosphere and Metals: Chemistry and Changes](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/cr500501m), *Chemical Reviews*